# select array of struct spark

Tags: java, python, scala, apache-spark

The question is part of complex problem that I am working on.I am stuck at a particular point. To minimize the problem statement let's say I have a dataframe created from json. Let's say to minimize the structure

The raw data is let's say somewhat like

```
{"person":[{"name":"david", "email": "david@gmail.com"}, {"name":"steve", "email":"steve@gmail.com"}]}
```

You can save this as person.json and create dataset as

```
Dataset<Row> df =  spark.read().json("person.json")
```

The schema / `printSchema()` has output-

```
root
 |-- person: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |


df.show(false);

+------------------------------------------------------------+
|       person                                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[david, david@gmail.com],[steve, steve@gmail.com]]         |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now the problem. As the part of code I have to do

```
df.select(array(struct(person.name, reverse(person.email)))
```

It's giving output like

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|       array(named_struct(person.name as `name`, person.e...|
+------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[[david, steve],[david@gmail.com, steve@gmail.com]]]       |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The schema get's updated to -

```
root
 |-- array(named_struct(name, person.name as `name`, email, person.email as `email`)): array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |--  name: array(nullable=true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |--  email: array(nullable=true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I do not want the schema and data to be changed. **What should I change in above `df.select`**

I am using Spark 2.3.0_2.11

On suggestion of user Someshwar
Tried using transform on it but its not available in lower version

```
df = df.withColumn("person_processed", expr("transform(person, x -> named_struct( 'email', reverse(x.email), 'name', x.name))"));
```

Below is stack trace for same -

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
extraneous input '>' expecting {'(', 'SELECT', 'FROM', 'ADD', 'AS', 'ALL', 'DISTINCT', 'WHERE', 'GROUP', 'BY', 'GROUPING', 'SETS', 'CUBE', 'ROLLUP', 'ORDER', 'HAVING', 'LIMIT', 'AT', 'OR', 'AND', 'IN', NOT, 'NO', 'EXISTS', 'BETWEEN', 'LIKE', RLIKE, 'IS', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'NULLS', 'ASC', 'DESC', 'FOR', 'INTERVAL', 'CASE', 'WHEN', 'THEN', 'ELSE', 'END', 'JOIN', 'CROSS', 'OUTER', 'INNER', 'LEFT', 'SEMI', 'RIGHT', 'FULL', 'NATURAL', 'ON', 'LATERAL', 'WINDOW', 'OVER', 'PARTITION', 'RANGE', 'ROWS', 'UNBOUNDED', 'PRECEDING', 'FOLLOWING', 'CURRENT', 'FIRST', 'AFTER', 'LAST', 'ROW', 'WITH', 'VALUES', 'CREATE', 'TABLE', 'DIRECTORY', 'VIEW', 'REPLACE', 'INSERT', 'DELETE', 'INTO', 'DESCRIBE', 'EXPLAIN', 'FORMAT', 'LOGICAL', 'CODEGEN', 'COST', 'CAST', 'SHOW', 'TABLES', 'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN', 'USE', 'PARTITIONS', 'FUNCTIONS', 'DROP', 'UNION', 'EXCEPT', 'MINUS', 'INTERSECT', 'TO', 'TABLESAMPLE', 'STRATIFY', 'ALTER', 'RENAME', 'ARRAY', 'MAP', 'STRUCT', 'COMMENT', 'SET', 'RESET', 'DATA', 'START', 'TRANSACTION', 'COMMIT', 'ROLLBACK', 'MACRO', 'IGNORE', 'BOTH', 'LEADING', 'TRAILING', 'IF', 'POSITION', '+', '-', '*', 'DIV', '~', 'PERCENT', 'BUCKET', 'OUT', 'OF', 'SORT', 'CLUSTER', 'DISTRIBUTE', 'OVERWRITE', 'TRANSFORM', 'REDUCE', 'SERDE', 'SERDEPROPERTIES', 'RECORDREADER', 'RECORDWRITER', 'DELIMITED', 'FIELDS', 'TERMINATED', 'COLLECTION', 'ITEMS', 'KEYS', 'ESCAPED', 'LINES', 'SEPARATED', 'FUNCTION', 'EXTENDED', 'REFRESH', 'CLEAR', 'CACHE', 'UNCACHE', 'LAZY', 'FORMATTED', 'GLOBAL', TEMPORARY, 'OPTIONS', 'UNSET', 'TBLPROPERTIES', 'DBPROPERTIES', 'BUCKETS', 'SKEWED', 'STORED', 'DIRECTORIES', 'LOCATION', 'EXCHANGE', 'ARCHIVE', 'UNARCHIVE', 'FILEFORMAT', 'TOUCH', 'COMPACT', 'CONCATENATE', 'CHANGE', 'CASCADE', 'RESTRICT', 'CLUSTERED', 'SORTED', 'PURGE', 'INPUTFORMAT', 'OUTPUTFORMAT', DATABASE, DATABASES, 'DFS', 'TRUNCATE', 'ANALYZE', 'COMPUTE', 'LIST', 'STATISTICS', 'PARTITIONED', 'EXTERNAL', 'DEFINED', 'REVOKE', 'GRANT', 'LOCK', 'UNLOCK', 'MSCK', 'REPAIR', 'RECOVER', 'EXPORT', 'IMPORT', 'LOAD', 'ROLE', 'ROLES', 'COMPACTIONS', 'PRINCIPALS', 'TRANSACTIONS', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'LOCKS', 'OPTION', 'ANTI', 'LOCAL', 'INPATH', STRING, BIGINT_LITERAL, SMALLINT_LITERAL, TINYINT_LITERAL, INTEGER_VALUE, DECIMAL_VALUE, DOUBLE_LITERAL, BIGDECIMAL_LITERAL, IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}(line 1, pos 21)

== SQL ==
transform(person, x -> named_struct( 'email', reverse(x.email), 'name', x.name))
---------------------^^^

    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException.withCommand(ParseDriver.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parse(ParseDriver.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkSqlParser.parse(SparkSqlParser.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.AbstractSqlParser.parseExpression(ParseDriver.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.expr(functions.scala:1308)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr(functions.scala)
    at com.mywork.jspark.JSparkMain1.main(JSparkMain1.java:43)
```

Comment: What are you want to get?

Comment: It's part of encoding logic. Where some fields of nested dataframe needs to be updated. I have udf created for updating value. Now to change them I am using df.select as shown above but it is changing schema tooo. I want to preserve schema of original dataframe.

Comment: Please specify what fields you want to update or put your expected output.. your question is not clear.

Comment: Tried to solve. please upvote + accept if it solve your problem

Comment: Forgot to mention but I am using spark 2.3

Comment: see edit-1, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I tried to approach this problem as following-

1. **`Load the data`**

```scala
  val spark = sqlContext.sparkSession
    val implicits = spark.implicits
    import implicits._
    val data =
      """
        |{"person":[{"name":"david", "email": "david@gmail.com"}, {"name":"steve", "email": "steve@gmail.com"}]}
      """.stripMargin
    val df = spark.read
      .json(data.split(System.lineSeparator()).toSeq.toDS())
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
```

Result-

```
+----------------------------------------------------+
|person                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|[[david@gmail.com, david], [steve@gmail.com, steve]]|
+----------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- person: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

2. **`Process the array<struct>`**

   > **This is tested for spark-2.4**

```
 val answer1 = df.withColumn("person_processed",
      expr("transform(person, x -> named_struct( 'email', reverse(x.email), 'name', x.name))"))
    answer1.show(false)
    answer1.printSchema()
```

Result-

```
+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|person                                              |person_processed                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|[[david@gmail.com, david], [steve@gmail.com, steve]]|[[moc.liamg@divad, david], [moc.liamg@evets, steve]]|
+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- person: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- person_processed: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

> Please observe both input "person" and "person_processed" column are of same type

### Edit-1 (As per comments, with case class)

> **User is on spark 2.3 where all higher order functions for map and array are no available, Below solution is for spark 2.3**

```scala
 // spark < 2.3
    case class InfoData(name: String, email: String)
    val infoDataSchema =
    ArrayType(StructType(Array(StructField("name", StringType), StructField("email", StringType))))

    val reverseEmailUDF = udf((arr1: mutable.WrappedArray[String], arr2: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => {
      if (arr1.length != arr2.length) null
      else arr1.zipWithIndex.map(t => InfoData(t._1, arr2(t._2).reverse))
    }, infoDataSchema)

    val spark2_3Processed = df
      .withColumn("person_processed",
          reverseEmailUDF(
            col("person.name").cast("array<string>"),
            col("person.email").cast("array<string>")
          )
      )

    spark2_3Processed.show(false)
    spark2_3Processed.printSchema()
```

Output-

```
+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|person                                              |person_processed                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|[[david@gmail.com, david], [steve@gmail.com, steve]]|[[david, moc.liamg@divad], [steve, moc.liamg@evets]]|
+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- person: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- person_processed: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
```

### Edit-2 (As per comments, without case class)

> **User is on spark 2.3 where all higher order functions for map and array are no available and case class creation is difficult. Below solution is for spark 2.3**

```scala
   val subSchema = df.schema("person").dataType

    val reverseEmailUDF_withoutCaseClass = //udf((nameArrayRow: Row, emailArrayRow: Row) => {
      udf((nameArray: mutable.WrappedArray[String], emailArray: mutable.WrappedArray[String]) => {
      if (nameArray.length != emailArray.length) null
      else nameArray.zipWithIndex.map(t => (t._1, emailArray(t._2).reverse))
    }, subSchema)

    val withoutCaseClasDF = df
      .withColumn("person_processed",
          reverseEmailUDF_withoutCaseClass(
            col("person.name").cast("array<string>"),
            col("person.email").cast("array<string>")
          )
      )

    withoutCaseClasDF.show(false)
    withoutCaseClasDF.printSchema()
    withoutCaseClasDF.select("person_processed.email").show(false)
```

Output-

```
+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|person                                              |person_processed                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|[[david@gmail.com, david], [steve@gmail.com, steve]]|[[david, moc.liamg@divad], [steve, moc.liamg@evets]]|
+----------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- person: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- person_processed: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)

+--------------+
|email         |
+--------------+
|[david, steve]|
+--------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Somesh. I tried above solution. It is giving sql.catatlyst.parse.ParserException at Line 1 Column 33. That is on where lambda starts..

I am using Java 1.8 and Spark 2.3

Comment: Some mistake in expression. Can you put the query you tried an Full stacktrace

Comment: I think that error because ```named_struct``` function is not available in ```spark 2.3``` version & it was introduced from ```spark 2.4+``` .

Comment: its there- https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.3.0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/complexTypeCreator.scala#L354. I'm checking here

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I checked named_stuct fuction inside functions package..

Comment: Can you put your code in description as edit -1 with stacktrace. It is very difficult for me to trace the reason?

Comment: @SomeshwarKale, is this ```transform``` function is available in ```spark 2.3.0 ``` ?? & I am checking in this - https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html & its not available in this link.

Comment: @Srinivas, yes it is not there in `spark 2.3.0 `, in fact highr order functions for complex datatypes were included after that :(

Comment: I added transform as Edit -1. I can not use case class. As mentioned this code is part of bigger problem where entire schema can be different. The dataset can be nested struct, array and masking has to be done for any given field name. I have handled Struct using recursion over schema but stuck in array part as above.

Comment: see edit-2, i hope it help, please accept and upvote, if it helps

Comment: Good Solution .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----------------------------------------------------+
|person                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|[[david@gmail.com, david], [steve@gmail.com, steve]]|
+----------------------------------------------------+

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- person: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)


scala> val finalDF = df
.select(explode($"person").as("person"))
.groupBy(lit(1).as("id"))
.agg(
    collect_list(
        struct(
            reverse($"person.email").as("email"),
            $"person.name").as("person")
        ).as("person")
    )
.drop("id")

finalDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [person: array<struct<email:string,name:string>>]

scala> finalDF.show(false)
+----------------------------------------------------+
|person                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|[[moc.liamg@divad, david], [moc.liamg@evets, steve]]|
+----------------------------------------------------+

scala> finalDF.printSchema
root
 |-- person: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)

scala>
```

Comment: This is the problem only. In schema of your answer name and email have become array while they were originally string

Comment: since you have not mentioned how you want expected output, I have just update answer, Please check now.

Comment: No srinivas, there seems to be confusion. The schema after read should be exact similar to Schema after transform that is reverse of email in this case. The 2 schema in answer have difference. I will say that you have done flattening

Comment: +----------------------------------------------------+
|person                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------+
|[[moc.liamg@divad, david], [moc.liamg@evets, steve]]|
+----------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- person: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- email: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)

Comment: Thanks for your help Srinivas! The solution works for exact 1 field in dataset. As the code is part of a bigger nested dataset which contains other 20-30 fields some of which are string and others are of type struct, so basically its not suitable for my problem.